# Jackson Databind not setting default value

Tags: kotlin, jackson, quarkus

In my quarkus application I have an endpoint that takes in a DTO, with a field that has a default value. When I don't send that field, I still get the exception

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.ValueInstantiationException: Cannot construct instance of
`FooDTO`, problem: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method
io.otherstuff.FooDTO.&lt;init&gt;, parameter someListVariable
at [Source: (io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxInputStream); line: 4, column: 1]
```

The class looks like this:

```
class FooDTO(
        override var someStringVar: String,
        override var someListVariable: List<Int> = emptyList(),
): BarDTO

---------------------------------------------

interface BarDTO {
    var someStringVar: String
    var someListVar: List<Int>
}
```

Now if I send a payload like this

```
{
    "someStringVar": "Hello Stackoverflow",
    "someListVar": []
}
```

it is working perfectly fine, but when I drop `"someListVar"` I get the exception from above, even though it should just initialize it as an empty list.
Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that during desalinization, the library (fasterxml) calls the primary constructor with null: `FooDTO("Hello Stackoverflow", null)`. The call ends up with the exception as the `someListVariable` parameter is not nullable (default value is used only when the paremeter is not provided at all, not when it's null).

One option of solving the problem would be providing an explicit [JsonCreator](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonCreator.html):

```kotlin
class FooDTO(
    override var someStringVar: String, 
    override var someListVariable: List<Int> = emptyList()) : BarDTO {

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic 
        @JsonCreator 
        fun of(
            @JsonProperty("someStringVar") someStringVar: String,
            @JsonProperty("someListVariable") someListVariable: List<Int>?) =
            FooDTO(someStringVar, someListVariable ?: emptyList())
    }
}
```

Another posibility is using secondary constructor instead of the default value:

```
class FooDTO : BarDTO {

    override var someStringVar: String
    override var someListVariable: List<Int>

    @JsonCreator
    constructor(
        @JsonProperty("someStringVar") someStringVar: String,
        @JsonProperty("someListVariable") someListVariable: List<Int>?) {
        this.someStringVar = someStringVar
        this.someListVariable = someListVariable ?: emptyList()
    }
}
```

Both options are unfortunately a bit verbose.